Data flow from Oracle to SQL Server using open query
I have a table in oracle server and I am trying to move the data in a SQL table, I created a linked server which works fine, when I try to move the data by specifying the where clause, it does not select the data only specified in the where clause. I use the following query. when I tried to only get order with the Calendar year 2021. below is the table I would like to query in oracle.
SELECT *
    FROM OPENQUERY (Linkedserver_A,
'select* 
from inventory.products  B  where  Calendar_year = 2021')

Output:



Order_Key
Order_Type
Trans_Type
Trans_Date
Calendar_year




1
13216584
M001
P
2019


2
13216584
M001
R1
2019


3
13216584
M001
R2
2019


4
13216584
M001
D
2021


5
76983231
M002
P
2018


6
76983231
M002
R1
2018


7
76983231
M002
R2
2018


8
76983231
M002
D
2019


9
93216548
M003
P
2021


10
93216548
M003
R1
2021


11
93216548
M003
R2
2021


12
93216548
M003
D
2022



This is what I did: I did the following query to get all the data for calendar_year 2021
SELECT *
    FROM OPENQUERY (Linkedserver_A,
                    'SELECT * 
                     FROM inventory.products B  
                     WHERE Calendar_year = 2021')


I am not sure of your data type for calendar year, but it looks incomplete to me = 2021' , shouldn't your condition look like where Calender_Year = '2021'')

I checked and it in Varchar Type data. I added a quote and getting  syntax error

You need to build a valid string including single quotes around 2021. There are lots of ways of doing this (concatenation, escaping the quotes, etc) but try '… ''2021'' '
